# How to transfer a function of two variables into one variable by change of variables?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

If $f(x,y)=y\, f(\frac{x}{y},1)=y\, g(\bar{x})=u(\bar{x})$ with $\bar{x}=\frac{x}{y}$,
then
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}=& \frac{\partial [y\, f(\frac{x}{y},1)]}{\partial x} \tag 1\\
=&  \frac{\partial [y\, g(\bar{x})]}{\partial x} \tag 2\\
=&\frac{\partial [y\, g(\bar{x})]}{\partial \bar{x}}\frac{\partial \bar{x}}{\partial x} \tag 3\\
=&\frac{\partial u(\bar{x})}{\partial \bar{x}}\frac{\partial \bar{x}}{\partial x}. \tag 4
\end{align}
How about $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y} $?
I'm a little confused.
Does it follow the derivation bellow?
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}=& \frac{\partial [y\, f(\frac{x}{y},1)]}{\partial y} \tag 5\\
=&  \frac{\partial [y\, g(\bar{x})]}{\partial y} \tag 6\\
=&y\, \frac{\partial g(\bar{x})}{\partial \bar{x}}\frac{\partial \bar{x}}{\partial y}+g(\bar{x}) \tag 7\\
=&\frac{\partial u(\bar{x})}{\partial \bar{x}}\frac{\partial \bar{x}}{\partial y}.\tag 8
\end{align}

Comment: $f(x,y)=yf(x/y,1)$ contradicts $f(x,y)=u(x/y)$. The first statement says that $f$ is homogeneous of degree 1, whereas the second - that $f$ is homogeneous of degree 0.

Comment: Thanks very much.  You mentioned me to notice the homogeneous of degree.

Comment: It is my pleasure, but I'm not sure, what you mean by "mentioned me to notice". Please do not hesitate to accept and upvote my answer below, if you find it helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer:

$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = g_{\bar x} (\bar x)$$

$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = g(\bar x) - \bar x g_{\bar x}(\bar x) $$

### Derivation:

We are given that $ f(x,y) = y f(x/y, 1) = y g(\bar x)$, where $\bar x = x/y$. Using the chain rule:

$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = y \cdot g_{\bar x} (\bar x) \cdot \frac{\partial \bar x}{\partial x}  = y \cdot g_{\bar x} (\bar x) \cdot \frac{1}{y} = g_{\bar x} (\bar x)$$

and

$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = g(\bar x) + y \cdot g_{\bar x} (\bar x) \cdot \frac{\partial \bar x}{\partial y}  = g(\bar x) + y \cdot g_{\bar x} (\bar x) \cdot \frac{-x}{y^2} = g (\bar x) - \frac{x}{y}g_{\bar x}(\bar x) = g(\bar x) - \bar x g_{\bar x}(\bar x) $$